# Need help for Mobile application Proxy connectivity with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, firewall, windows-firewall

I am trying to record Mobile application via jmeter for which I have done all the necessary setup in mobile device and desktop jmeter. I am facing issues with Windows Firewall as it is blocking all incoming traffic from the mobile, as this machine is administered by my organization i cannot turn off the firewall, any suggestions on how I can allow the traffic with firewall enabled?

Due to proxy setup the traffic will always come from a single port although the IP address may change depending upon the device.

[Screenshot of all dropped requests arriving from Mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kghs2.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask your network administrators instead of JMeter community in the Internet
2. Get yourself a separate Wi-Fi adapter which can act as an access point and connect your mobile device to it
3. Use an [emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) or [simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html) instead of real device so everything will happen on your machine
4. Install a [sniffer tool](https://techwiser.com/wireshark-alternatives-for-android/) on the device and capture traffic there directly, once you have a [.pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) or [.har](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) file you can use [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/) for transforming it into a JMeter script.